# How can I get the ghost image when dragging to be an HTML template?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a column that has several boxes, each with some text in them. These boxes have data that I use when creating a component. Right now I have a single component, and based on what the user would select, the component would render a bit different. For simplicity of this question, let's say that the component just looks like this:

```
<div class='rect'>
    <div class='name'>
        {{model.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Depending on what the user drags, I want to create a ghost image of my rect component, with the model's name correctly displayed. Now normally, you can set the ghost image like this:

```
document.getElementById("drag-something").addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
    var crt = this.cloneNode(true);
    crt.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    document.body.appendChild(crt);
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(crt, 0, 0);
}, false);
```

the issue is that I want to pass in a template along with some data. Is this possible? In reality, my component will have more differences depending on which item is dragged, and there will be many different items to drag. Is it possible to do this with a template, or is there some other trick for this?